# Cumulative Distribution function support change

Tags: probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

Consider parameter $u$ has a cumulative distribution function $F$, with continous density $f$, and that has support $[m,n]$. Suppose the lower support point $m$ is changed to a new point $v$, where $v>m$. In this case, can I describe the new CDF function with the old $F$ or I need to develop a new PDF and therefore CDF functions?

Comment: It is not clear how did the distribution change according to the support is changed. We can know how the support is change when we know how the distribution is changed, but not vice versa, unless we have more information.
For example, is $u$ undergoes a linear transformation? If yes, then we can find out the relationship between the old CDF and the new CDF.

Comment: Think of $F$ as a demand function with the support $[m,n]$. Later, the firm received a signal from the market and realised that the lower bound for the distribution is not $m$ but $v$.

Comment: I am not very familiar with econometric, that could be a truncated distribution

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look.